# Pan around the canvas within bounds smoothly

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, pan

Most other solutions I have found relate to images as the bounds and work through css, and I can't get them to work with a canvas.

I want to create the bounds by defining an arbitrary percent size of the canvas (e.g 2x - twice the size) that expands from the center of the canvas and then have the canvas view (red) move/pan around within the bounds (green) by mouse hovering inside the canvas - that it moves to all corners of the bounds from the center of the canvas.

[image]

like this behavior in terms of the direction with panning

http://jsfiddle.net/georgedyer/XWnUA/2/

Additionally, I would like

- the solution to work with a responsive canvas sizes rather than fixed canvas sizes
- the panning to be smooth using easing such as CubicInOut easing
- to detect the mouse hover inside the circle drawn. Might have to change the coordinate from screen to world to get it to work properly. But maybe theirs an easier way?

[image]

**formulas**

Here's my attempt at figuring out the formulas to get it working! I'll just focus on just one axis (x-axis) from left to right of the mouse, but the same formulas should apply to the y-axis.

First I get the "percentX" of the mouse along the width. If the "percentX" is 0 then the "newX" for the pan will be the value of the leftSide, else if it's 1 then it'll be the rightSide of the boundsBorder (green). So the "percentX" determines which side of the boundsBorder/limit the canvas view will extend/move to.

Only problem is that this doesn't work. So my formula must be wrong. The mouse inside the circle event is also inaccurate because of my canvas translate. Combining everything together is difficult to figure out!

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Panning</title>

    <style type="text/css">
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.canvas-container {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
}

.container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- CANVAS -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="canvas-container">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SCRIPT -->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
var height = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
var panX = 0, panY = 0;
var scaleBorderFactor = 2; /* scale factor for the bounds */
var mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

function Circle(x, y, radius, color){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.color = color;
    this.draw = function(ctx){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
}

/* Rect Stroke Borders for visual reference */
function RectBorder(x, y, w, h, c){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.color = c;
    this.draw = function(ctx){
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    /* Draw rect from a center point */
    this.drawAtCenter = function(ctx){
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = 2;
        ctx.strokeRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    };
    this.toString = function(){
        console.log("x: "+this.x+", y: "+this.y+", w: "+this.width+", h: "+this.height+", color = "+this.color);
    }
}

function getMousePos(canvas, event) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
        x: (event.clientX - rect.left),
        y: (event.clientY - rect.top)
    };
}

function insideCircle(circle, mouse){
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.x - mouse.x,2) + Math.pow(circle.y - mouse.y,2));
    console.log(circle.radius+", d = "+dist)
    return dist <= circle.radius;
}

function lerp(start, end, percent){
  return start*(1 - percent) + percent*end;
}

/* t: current time, b: beginning value, c: change in value, d: duration */
function easeInOutCubic(t, b, c, d) {
    if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t*t + b;
    return c/2*((t-=2)*t*t + 2) + b;
}

var canvasBorder = new RectBorder(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'red');

var boundsBorder = new RectBorder(-(canvas.width*scaleBorderFactor - canvas.width)/2,-(canvas.height*scaleBorderFactor - canvas.height)/2,canvas.width*scaleBorderFactor,canvas.height*scaleBorderFactor,'green');

var circle = new Circle(200,200,40,'blue');

/* Draw Update */
update();

function update(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    width = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    height = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.save();

    /* MOUSE */
    percentX = (mouse.x / width);
    percentY = (mouse.y / height);

    /* the 2 sides of boundsBorder */
    var leftSide = (width*scaleBorderFactor - width)/2 - width;
    var rightSide = (width*scaleBorderFactor - width)/2 + width;

    var topSide = (height*scaleBorderFactor - height)/2 - width;
    var bottomSide = (height*scaleBorderFactor - height)/2 + height;


    newX = rightSide * percentX + leftSide * (1 - percentX);
    newY = bottomSide * percentY + topSide * (1 - percentY);


    /* maybe use easeInOutCubic for better smoothness */
    panX = lerp(-newX, mouse.x, 0.1);
    panY = lerp(-newY, mouse.y, 0.1);

    if (insideCircle(circle, mouse)){
        circle.color = "pink";
    } else {
        circle.color = "blue";
    }

    ctx.translate(panX,panY);

    /* Draw both borders only for reference */
    canvasBorder.draw(ctx);
    boundsBorder.drawAtCenter(ctx);

    /* Draw Circle */
    circle.draw(ctx);

    ctx.restore();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

/* Events */
function mousemove(e) {
    mouse = getMousePos(canvas, e);
}

/* Event Listeners */
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

I have managed to get the pan functionality to work. I just realized that all I need to do is offset by the positive and negative "widthGap"(see picture below) amount when panning. So it goes from positive "widthGap" (moves to the rght) to negative "widthGap" (moves to the left) when the "percentX" changes value like mentioned previously.

To get the smooth movement, I instead applied the lerp to the "percentX" values.

[image]

The code below is what should be replaced from the previous code above. It also shows the new variables I defined, which will make some of the variables from the previous code redundant.

**UPDATED Code**

```
var canvasBorder = new RectBorder(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'red');

/* widthGap is the new leftSide formula.
*  it is the gap differance between border and canvas
*/
var widthGap = (canvas.width*scaleBorderFactor - canvas.width)/2;
var heightGap = (canvas.height*scaleBorderFactor - canvas.height)/2;

var boundsBorder = new RectBorder(-widthGap,-heightGap,canvas.width+widthGap*2,canvas.height+heightGap*2,'green');

var circle = new Circle(200,200,40,'blue');

/* Draw Update */
update();

var newPercentX = 0, newPercentY = 0;
var percentX = 0, percentY = 0;

function update(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    width = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    height = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    ctx.save();

    newPercentX = (mouse.x / width);
    newPercentY = (mouse.y / height);

    /* MOUSE */
    percentX = lerp(percentX,newPercentX,0.05);
    percentY = lerp(percentY,newPercentY,0.05);

    panX = (widthGap) * percentX + (-widthGap) * (1 - percentX);
    panY = (heightGap) * percentY + (-heightGap) * (1 - percentY);

    ctx.translate(-panX,-panY);

    if (insideCircle(circle, mouse)){
        circle.color = "pink";
    } else {
        circle.color = "blue";
    }

    /* Draw both borders only for reference */
    canvasBorder.draw(ctx);
    boundsBorder.drawAtCenter(ctx);

    /* Draw Circle */
    circle.draw(ctx);

    ctx.restore();

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```